# Non-variable expression in variable definition context compilation error

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran2003

I am getting this compilation error with gfortran 5.4 and a .f90 code

```
call abc_output(struc,nx,ny,nz,'AB'   ,get_ab_dat(p_f),&
                                                1
Error: Non-variable expression in variable definition context (actual argument to INTENT = OUT/INOUT) at (1)
```

The method call that is generating the compilation error is shown below
and the error is on get_ab_dat

```
type(b_f)                :: p_f
call abc_output(struc,nx,ny,nz,'AB'   ,get_ab_dat(p_f),&
                               'BD'   ,get_bc_dat(p_f),&
                               'EF' ,  aaa )
```

The function get_ab_dat is shown below

```
function get_ab_dat(bf) result(qx_arr)
  type(b_f),intent(in) :: bf
  real,dimension(:,:,:),allocatable :: qx_arr
  qx_arr = bf%qx
end function get_ab_dat


subroutine abc_output (struc,nx,ny,nz,dname1,data1,&
       dname2,data2,dname3,data3,dname4,data4)

type(c_s),intent(in)                 :: struc
integer,intent(in)                           :: nx,ny,nz     
character(len=*),intent(in)                  :: dname1
real,dimension(:,:,:),allocatable,intent(inout)          :: data1
character(len=*),intent(in),optional         :: dname2,dname3,dname4    
real,dimension(:,:,:),allocatable,intent(inout),optional ::                 data2,data3,data4
```

Can somebody explain what that error means and how I can fix it ?

Comment: Please show the full code and the full error message. Where does (1)  in the error message point to?

Comment: BTW, your code is not Fortran 90, but Fortran 2003, so the fortran90 tag is confusing. File extension .f90 does not mean Fortran 90, it means fixed form source.

Comment: perhaps associated with `abc_output`, show that.

Comment: @agentp - abc_output is very big. Can I just post the declaration part at the top ?

Comment: Yes, you can. In fact, the intents of the arguments suffice. It is probably a duplicate anyway.

Comment: before making other fixes, take a good look at `abc_output` and determine if it actually needs to be `allocatable,inout`.  Just as a matter of style it strikes me odd an subroutine named "output" would be allocating arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot post an expression or a constant to an `intent(OUT)` or `intent(INOUT)` argument. You must always pass a variable, because it can be changed in the procedure you are calling.

So because the sixth argument of `abc_output` is `intent(OUT)` or (more likely) `intent(INOUT)` you first have to assign the value of `get_ab_dat(p_f)` to a variable and you have to pass the variable to `abc_output`. Be careful about argument aliasing.

In this particular case the argument is also `allocatable`, so the variable must be `allocatable` as well.